# Using JEST on a "Laravel + React" project to test the app API (Backend)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, jestjs, laravel-5.7

I followed this tutorial:

https://blog.pusher.com/react-laravel-application/

I did both parts: `Backend` and `Frontend`.

When I ran the application (after compiling the `Frontend` with: `$ npm run dev`), I ran the the `Laravel` application with: `$ php artisan serve`.

With the application, I was able to create a `Project`, but when trying to create a new `Task` I got a `500 Internal Server Error` from the `API` (`Backend`) as you can see below:

[image]

As you can see, on the image above, the requested route was: `/api/tasks` (`POST` method).

On file: `/routes/api.php` I have the following content:

```
<?php
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
Route::post('projects', 'ProjectController@store');
Route::get('projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show');
Route::put('projects/{project}', 'ProjectController@markAsCompleted');
Route::post('tasks', 'TaskController@store');
Route::put('tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@markAsCompleted');
?>
```

On file: `app/Http/Controllers/TaskController.php` I have the following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $projects = Project::where('is_completed', false)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_completed', false);
            }])->get();
        return $projects->toJson();
    }
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
        $project = Project::create([
            'name' => $validatedData['name'],
            'description' => $validatedData['description'],
        ]);
        return response()->json('Project created!');
    }
    public function show($id) {
        $project = Project::with(['tasks' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_completed', false);
        }])->find($id);
        return $project->toJson();
    }
    public function markAsCompleted(Project $project) {
        $project->is_completed = true;
        $project->update();
        return response()->json('Project updated!');
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot this problem and also, detect this kind of problems in early stages of the development without having to have the `Frontend` already implemented, since this problem is happening on the `Backend`.

**Then, my question is:** How can I use the test framework: `JEST` (which it is very recommended by lot of developers) with this **specific** `Laravel` + `React` project?

Please, provide all the information you can on this. I will really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What did your log file say the error was?

Comment: We cant see the error. Show the response tab in the developer console and/or share the `laravel.log` trace. if you inspect these its probably really obvious what is wrong

Answer (score 8):

I might be late here. hope this helps to those who are looking to setup a jest test environment for laravel projects using react preset.

**Installation and configuration**

Install jest as dev dependency

```
npm install jest --save-dev
```

Create a new config file for jest in project root `jest.config.js`

```
/**jest.config.js**/
module.exports = {
  testRegex: 'resources/js/test/.*.test.js$'
}
```

add `test` command to `package.json`. see i have added `"scripts": { "test": "jest"}` . your package.json file might be different. i pasted my whole package.json just for presentation purpose. no need to replace it all with this. just the script test part need to be added.

```
/**package.json**/
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

It's done

**Now to test whether it works**

Create a sample test `resources/js/test/index.test.js`

```
/**resources/js/test/index.test.js**/
test('it works', () => {
  expect(1 + 2).toBe(3)
})
```

finally test it by running

```
npm test
```

Output will be something like

```
> @ test /home/aimme/docker/demoproject
> jest

 PASS  resources/js/test/index.test.js
  ✓ it works (3ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.025s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: I followed the steps here but my Test can recognise the component I'm testing, see details of my error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376159/getting-jest-to-work-with-babel-laravel-mix

Comment: Where is the *"test the app API (Backend)"* part covered? This answer is **half way** regarding OP question.