# getting jest to work with babel / laravel-mix

Tags: reactjs, laravel-mix, babel-jest

I'm using `jest` and `testing-library/react` for tests of my ReactJS components in a `Laravel` app.

My tests break because the component to to test isn't recognised by jest even after importing it into the test. I have the following settings in `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  testRegex: 'resources/js/tests/.*.test.js$',
  roots: ["<rootDir>/resources/js/"],
  moduleDirectories: ["resources/js/components", "resources/js/containers", "resources/js/views", "node_modules"]
}
```

And in the `package.json` file

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
```

Here's a simple test that fails due to error

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import axiosMock from "axios";
// the component to test
import BlogEditor from "../../components/BlogEditor/BlogEditor";
jest.mock("axios");

test("Blog Editor recieves props and renders", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
        <BlogEditor
            tags={[{ id: 1, name: "A tag"}]}
            suggestions={[{id: 2, name: "A Suggestion"}]}
        />
    );
});
```

The error I get is rather cryptic

Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: /Users/anadi/Code/adminpanel/resources/js/tests/BlogEditor/BlogEditor.test.js: Unexpected token (16:8)

  14 | test("Blog Editor recived props and renders element", () => {
  15 |     const { getByTestId } = render(
> 16 |         <BlogEditor
     |         ^
  17 |             tags={[{ id: 1, name: "A tag"}]}
  18 |             suggestions={[{id: 2, name: "A Suggestion"}]}
  19 |         />

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:150:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1123:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:529:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:509:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:279:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:234:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:185:21)
  at Parser.parseExprListItem (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2077:18)
  at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:817:14)
```

Comment: What does your component look like? I'm having trouble testing my component because of the way props are passed from controllers to components. Right now, I render my component only if a certain div is in the dom. The props are then taken from said div through the data attribute and passed to component. I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my babel and jest configurations, moved jest configuration to `package.json` (I have no clue why this actually helped) but it did

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "clearMocks": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "testRegex" : "resources/js/tests/.*.test.js$",
    "roots": ["<rootDir>/resources/js/"],
    "moduleDirectories": ["resources/js/components", "resources/js/containers", "resources/js/views", "node_modules"],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/resources/js/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/resources/js/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
```

and updated the babel configuration too

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```